# Hiding visibility hides image but still reveals space taken by hidden element

Tags: javascript, localhost, visibility

A fixed navbar appears when the user scrolls past the logo in the header(100vh). (The point at which this switch happens is at 220px scrolltop.) Making use of javaScript's `.visibility: hidden/visible`, this works as desired in the [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/59/)

On the localhost, however, it works but once the navbar appears at 220px, the remainder of the header(100vh *minus* 200px) shows below the navbar as white(only the image is hidden). What could the issue be?

The code on the localhost is exactly the same as in the fiddle & there are no console errors.

**Would also like to add** that I'm not using jquery because it causes a conflict with another item using jquery inspite of using `jQuery.noConflict();`.

Comment: Have you tried `display: none/block` ?

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `element.visibility=visible|hidden;` do. it's make the object invisible but reserve space.

And different from `element.display=block|none;`, which hiding element and also remove the space.

I altered your example with `display:none/block` : https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/62

And also the problem of `nav` disappear, because it's inside `header`. just move it out it's should be fine :
https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/63

Comment: thanks, but when i used the same with the navbar, it's not working ie. navbar is not showing up at all: https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/59/

Comment: @AgniScribe Ahh, I see.

the prblem is because your `nav` is in side `header`. when you hide `header` the nav disappear.

Just move `nav` out of header should fix problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/63/

Comment: thanks, it's working for me now (though the fiddle has some issues: https://jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/59/). On my localhost the navbar is appearing after 220px, but it jumps 400px more before appearing? any ideas?(sorry to bother you like this)

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like below in javascript
    document.getElementById('id').style.display='none';

Hope this helps.

Comment: adds a lot of inconsistency and doesn't work ultimately

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then no need to write long code of core JavaScript.

```
$('#navig').hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
        $('#arr_downpoint').hide();

    }
    else {

        $('#arr_downpoint').show();
        $('#header').show();
        $('#navig').hide();

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 220) {
            $('#header').hide();
            $('#navig').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the navigation is not showing at all: jsfiddle.net/qz7531bu/61/  . also, i would have liked to use jquery but it is interfering with other blocks of code making use of jquery, inspite of using `$j=jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: You just asked to hide an image. So I have done that.

Comment: No, my issue was that the image was being hidden but the space it occupied was still there (showing up as white space)